# How to create a Linq To Entities expression

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, lambda

HI, I'm using Linq To Entities and I'd like to convert this

```
return db.Products
         .Where(p => p.idUser.Equals(id) && 
                     p.Category.Genre.Any(g => g.visible))
```

into something like

```
Func<Genre, bool> expr = g => g.visible

return db.Products
         .Where(p => p.idUser.Equals(id) && 
                     p.Category.Genre.Any(expr))
```

so I can add more complexity with something like this

```
Func<Genre, bool> expr = g => g.visible
expr += g => g.position < 5
```

But I always have an 'internal 1025 error .NET'.
Can anyone help me, please?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `Expression`s, not delegates. You can use the [`PredicateBuilder`](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) class by Joseph Albahari to build your predicate dynamically :

```
Expression<Func<Genre, bool>> expr = g => g.visible;
expr = expr.And(g => g.position < 5);
```